# CSS3 animate slide/hide navigation to influence other elements

Tags: html, css, css-animations

[image: Animated navigation slide to display/hide needs to push content down the page]

I would like to have a smooth animated transition of 1 & 2, when 1 is triggered to display. I have accomplished this here: http://codepen.io/jacksonbeale/pen/epjcs using a negative top margin, but the problem is that the height of 1 will vary depending on the number of items in the navigation, so this will not work for me.

```
nav {
    margin-top:-95px;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    z-index:5;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    &.showmenu {
      margin-top:0;
    }
  }
```

My current project does not allow me to use jQuery, and any js needs to be written by another developer. I only have control over html & css. I seem to be running in to this issue a bit so it would be great if someone could offer a suggestion on a pure css method to accomplish what I need.

Comment: you're already using jQuery to do the toggle, so what is really your limitation to keep using it? are you only allowed to use the toggle, ie that's already built in...? i personally don't think you can calculate height only using CSS, but others may think otherwise...

Comment: Hi @webeno. I used jQuery on codepen to emulate what they are doing in their app with angularjs. I could request for them to write what I need in angular, but I'm more curious to see if there is an alternative css route. Is there a way to animate this slide in without calculating height at all?

Comment: yeah, that's what i found, i don't think it's possible, but let's see what the others say... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this :

- Add a container around the menu and the content
- Position your content absolutely
- Then, as the container only has the height of the menu (content is out of flow with `position:absolute;`) you can use translateY to togggle the menu in and out with `translateY(-100%)`/`translateY(0)`

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/HLndb?editors=110)**

*HTML :*

```
<div class="test">
  <div><span class="menulink">Menu</span></div>
  <div class="content">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS :* (sorry I'm not used to SCSS)

```
.test {
  width:400px;
  position:relative;
  > div, nav {
    border:3px solid #CCC;
  }
  > div:first-child {
    height:30px;
    z-index:10;
    background:teal;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    span {
      float:right;
      display:table;
      height:100%;
      &:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
      }
    }
  }
  nav {
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    z-index:5;
    &.showmenu {
      margin-top:0;
    }
  }
}
.content > div{
  min-height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-3px; top:100%;
    width:100%;
  border:3px solid #ccc;
}
.content{
  z-index:0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.content.showmenu{
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}
```

*jQuery :*

```
$( ".menulink" ).click(function() {
  $( ".content" ).toggleClass( "showmenu" );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @web-tiki. It looks like it may well work :) I'm going to need to play around with it over the weekend though as I've run out of time right now. I'll give you a tick once I've confirmed. Thanks again!

Comment: This seems to work well, although some of my existing css needs to be reworked to suit, I think this could be the way forward :) Thanks @web-tiki !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add This code in your project.

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/3ux0du19/)

Set css style like this.

```
<style>
    .menu {
        max-width: 500px;
        background-color: #000;
    }
    .menu a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
.menu ul{
        padding:0px;
        position:relative;
        z-index:999;            
}
    .menu > ul > li{
        display: inline;    
        position: relative;
    }
    .menu > ul > li a{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 15px;
    }
    .menu li ul{
        top: 120%;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width:100%;
        max-width: 150px;
        transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    .menu li ul li{
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
    }        
    .menu li:hover > ul{
            opacity:1;  
            visibility:visible;
            top:100%;
    }
    .menu ul ul > li > ul{
        top: 0% !important;
        left: 120%;
    }
    .menu ul ul li:hover > ul{
        left: 100%;
    }
.no-padding{
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }

</style
```

And Set HTML Code Like this.

```
<nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
```